# Inserting element into predefined Show object

Tags: graphics

I have a predefined function that consists of a number plots combined with Show.  Is it possible to add another graphics object at a particular position from the function directly?  Simplified example:

```
figure[x0_] := Show[{
Plot[x - x0, {x, -10, 10}],
Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}],
Plot[x^3, {x, -10, 10}]
}];
figure[2]
```

[image: output1]

I want to be able to generate something analogous to:

```
block = Graphics[{LightRed, Rectangle[{-20, -20}, {0, 0}]}];
Show[{
Plot[x - 2, {x, -10, 10}],
Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}],
block,
Plot[x^3, {x, -10, 10}]
}]
```

[image: output2]

with *figure(2]* and *block* directly, something functionally similar to

```
Insert[output[2],block,3]
```

The key point being that the order matters.  Is there a convenient way of doing so?

Comment: `Insert[figure[2], block[[1]], {1, 3}]`?

Comment: It seems that the most straightforward thing is to combine them using the `Show` statement as follows: `Show[{ figure[2], block }]`.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch The OP wants to insert `block` between the 2nd part and the 3rd part of `figure[2]` and precises that the "order matters", hence my answer.

Comment: @ andre314 Exactly that I do not understand, since the result is the same.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch In this case yes. But it is possible that the OP has over-simplified his example.

Comment: @andre314 Difficult to imagine.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I did a mistake in my last comment when I said "In this case yes". In fact, on my machine `Show[{figure[2], block}]` is different from what gives my code. See the Edit in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Insert[figure[2], block[[1]], {1, 3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
figure[x0_] := 
  Show[{Plot[x - x0, {x, -10, 10}], Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}], 
    Plot[x^3, {x, -10, 10}]}];  

block = Graphics[{LightRed, Rectangle[{-20, -20}, {0, 0}]}];  

Show[
   Graphics[figure[2][[1, 1]]]
 , Graphics[figure[2][[1, 2]]]
 , block
 , Graphics[figure[2][[1, 3]]]
 , Options[figure[2]]]
```

[image]

`Options[figure[2]]` retrieves the original options of `figure[2]` that are lost when extracting
`Graphics[figure[2][[1, 1]]]`.

**EDIT**

Note that `Show[{ figure[2], block }]`doesn't give the result expected by the OP :

```
> Show[{ figure[2], block }]
```

[image]